# Logic of ether transfer while minting NFT

Tags: solidity, web3js, erc-721, ethers.js, mint

Recently wrote a simple smart contract with erc721 and minted an nft (payable). And got to transfer ether from user to contract
using `msg.value`

Wondering where the actual logic for transferring ether to contract is written.

All I did was passed some ether as value while calling smart contract method.

Answer (score 0):

Sending Ether to a contract only requires two things:

1. The sender has to include the Ether in the transaction, in its `value` field
2. The receiving contract has to have a `payable` function in order to receive incoming Ether (except some edge cases, such as receiving selfdestructed Ether which doesn't require `payable`)

Otherwise there really isn't anything you *have to* do - the contract will simply receive the Ether and add it to its Ether balance. If you need, you can build some logic around the `msg.value` to for example check how much Ether was sent.

Comment: yes did both, got it working. But i just wanted to go through the implementation under the hood,  the logic where ether is transferred from user to contract.

Comment: Ah you mean that. That's all in the node client implementation code. As is all of the blockchain code. The blockchain is just a bunch of node clients talking with each other and running compatible code.

Comment: any idea where i can get that?

Comment: Here's the most common client, Geth: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum